# Unexpected loss of reputation

Tags: support, suggested-edits, reputation, deleted-questions

I made a comment earlier today on a post requesting more detail. The question was removed and I lost two reputation points. I am puzzled. How can I lose points for requesting an improvement to a question?

Comment: Did you edit the question?

Comment: I'm not sure, as I can't see the question anymore.

Comment: Maybe the user went away.

Answer (score 5):

You made a suggested edit on the question, which was approved, thus giving you 2 reputation points.

When the question was deleted, these were gone too.

Comment: Okay, thanks,  I understand that, but the result was a net loss of two points hence puzzlement. It may not have been the question I thought it was; how can I see the question?

Comment: You can't, not before you have 10k reputation (and a link to the question). Again, a net loss of 2 points corresponds to the 2 points gained from an accepted suggested edit.

Comment: And it's not a "net loss of two points" - it's a net change of zero. +2 (suggested edit approved) - 2 (post deleted) = 0. You're back to where you were before the edit.