# Inaccuracy of reputation points

Tags: bug, reputation

In my reputation, I scored 700 some days (~1 week) ago, but since Monday, Stack Overflow and the Stack Exchange network shows 696 reputation points. I re-calculated all the plus points and minus points and came to a result of 713. So how can this happen?

Can this be affected through approved editing of posts which are deleted like here: [Unexpected loss of reputation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/312198/unexpected-loss-of-reputation)?

Comment: Basically - yes. A post you made two successful suggested edits to on Oct 24th was removed by the roomba on Nov 26th (so -4 rep).